# rename image while uploading it to server

Tags: php

i am trying to upload the image, but i want that if the image already exists then i need to rename the file. The problem in my code arises when i try to upload the image after renaming the file. the part of code where i am facing issue is. after renaming if i echo the name of the file it gets changed but after it i am not able to upload the image to server

```
if(file_exists($target_file))
    {
        $new_filename =  uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['imageFileType'];
        rename($target_file, $new_filename);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
            {
                $name=basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                echo $name;
            } 
        else 
            {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
    }
else    
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
            {
                $name=basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                echo $name;
            } 
        else 
            {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }

    }
```

the entire code that i have for uploading the image is

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$target_dir = "catpic/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
    {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) 
            {
                //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            }
        else 
            {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
    }

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    }
else 
    {
        if(file_exists($target_file))
            {
                $new_filename =  uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['imageFileType'];
                rename($target_file, $new_filename);
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
                    {
                        $name=basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                        echo $name;
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }
            }
        else    
            {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
                    {
                        $name=basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                        echo $name;
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }

            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more what the error is ?

Comment: @Zgr3doo the error is that my image is not getting uploaded after the renaming part. if i upload the image for the first time it is fine but if i upload the same image next time it does not get uploaded although its name gets changed

Comment: You missing path in your $new_filename - also it may be good idea to use the way which is commonly used in file upload scripts and assign random hash as a name to uploaded files and save this hash to the database along with id of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing path in $new_filename

compare both declarations

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$new_filename =  uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['imageFileType'];
```

I'm updating my answer to match your suggestion try to replace this section of your code

```
$new_filename =  uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['imageFileType'];
rename($target_file, $new_filename);
```

with

```
$new_filename = $target_dir . uniqid() . '.' . $imageFileType;
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $new_filename)){
```

simply add $target_dir and just delete rename() as its not needed

basically what you did in previous code when file existed during upload you was trying to rename old file using rename() which probably not succeed and after that you was trying to upload new file with the same conflicting name

Comment: i tried this also but my condition is going to else part only even if the file already exists

Comment: I see that when file already exist you renaming old file and after that you still trying to upload to target_file is that correct?

Comment: can you check if renaming is successful?

Comment: i want that if i upload the file, if it does not exist then it gets uploaded simply, BUT if i upload an image with a name that is already present then the new image should get renamed and then the upload process should continue

Comment: i replaced my code with your code, when i printed the $new_filename to check result i got this result catpic/55643e8e04ccd. and it created a downloadable blank file on my server with the name 55643e8e04ccd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78780/discussion-between-zgr3doo-and-roy).